# calling a method of a class on one object , affect another object in the same class

Tags: python, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)
>   [Unexpected connections between class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564145/unexpected-connections-between-class-instances)

here is my code to build a class called Neuron:

```
class Neuron():
  def __init__(self,connection=[]):
      self.connection=connection
  def makeConnection(self,other):
      self.connection.append(other)
  def getConnection(self):
      return self.connection
```

as you see each object of this class has it's own connection to other objects of the same class. Now i build a group of Neurons :

```
P=[]
for i in range(5):
   P.append(Neuron())
```

Now , i want to make connections between my neurons: let's do something simple:

```
 P[1].makeConnection(P[2])
```

now when i check in python :

```
 P[2].getConnection()
```

it gives me P[2] in it's connection list! i just applied makeConnection method on P[1], where on earth I connected P[2] to itself!?! please someone help!

Comment: Did you not bother reading the link that was included when your previous question was closed?

Comment: Please do *not* open duplicates with the exact same content.

Comment: Dupe of [Unexpected connections between class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13564145)

Comment: sorry I thought it had nothing with my question but now I see your point man...!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
def __init__(self, connection=[]):
      self.connection = connection
```

to

```
def __init__(self, connection=None):
      if connection is None:
          connection = []
      self.connection = connection
```

Otherwise all your objects end up referring to the same list. When you change one neuron's connections, all other neurons change too.

Comment: wow... that was great! i couldn't figure it out ! but how come connection=[] does not mean empty list. i thought it would make a new empty list for each object...i know where things went wrong but now i'm confused! :) thank you !

Comment: @Sun: It makes a new list once, when the function is defined, and keeps using that list over and over again. It does not make a new list every time you call the function.

Comment: @Sun: Spending two minutes reading the question we linked you to would have solved this for you as well.